# NSXMLParser crashing on invalid XML

Tags: iphone, xml, ios, ios4, nsxmlparser

I have a parser working correctly when the input is in valid XML form.  Is there any way for me to know when an XML document isn't correctly formatted and to recover from that without my application crashing?

NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
    success = [xmlParser parse];

The application crashes when calling [xmlParser parse] and does not call my parseErrorOccurred delegate method.

**EDIT**
It has nothing to do with the parser my parseErrorOccurred delegate method was causing the crash.  An oversight with calling NSLog was causing the issue.

Comment: Where does the parser crash? Provide some sample code.

Comment: It crashes when I give it a non-conforming XML document and doesn't call my parseErrorOccurred delegate method.

Comment: What exact line of code crashes - as soon as it crashes type "bt" in the debugger console, and post that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the NSXMLParserDelegate has a method `parser:parseErrorOccurred:` which is supposedly called when a fatal error has occured, so you can catch it there and decide on how to proceed (all the info you have parsed thus far is available).

I assume the crash occurs, because the parser isn't returning what was expected of it, so if you catch the error happening and try to fix the data and/or replace something necessary then your app shouldn't crash anymore.